# How to select text in tinymce editor, if I know it's position in html content?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, selection

The question is pretty simple, but I'm struggling to find any simple solution to make it work. I'm working with TinyMCE in the Wordpress.

Let's say that I have a position of some word in the html content, which I can get from editor like this:

```
tinymce.activeeditor.getContent();
```

So i need to select this word and move to selection (scroll to it).
For example, if content contains something like this:

```
...Bla bla bla some <strong>text</strong> and more text and banana and <img src=.../> more text bla blaa...
```

You can see the word "banana" out there, which, for example, I want to select. I know its position, let's say its start_pos = 30, end_pos = 35. It's not necessary a word, it can be a phrase (several words), but I know it's position, so there is no difference.

I need a way to select it in the Visual Editor (or Rich Editor), like I do for textarea (if Text mode is active) like this:

```
    // cl_editor_lastfocus is textarea
    cl_editor_lastfocus.setSelectionRange(start, end);

    let charsPerRow = cl_editor_lastfocus.cols;
    let selectionRow = (start - (start % charsPerRow)) / charsPerRow;
    let lineHeight = cl_editor_lastfocus.clientHeight / cl_editor_lastfocus.rows;

    // scroll !!
    cl_editor_lastfocus.scrollTop = lineHeight * selectionRow;
    cl_editor_lastfocus.focus();
```

Is it possible? As far as I can see, most answers here suggest to select textnode with this text and then set selection range. But I have no idea which textnode I have to select because my desired word can be anywhere in the document. Also, I can do that by wrapping the word with a span and then select this span node, but I don't want to keep that span afterwards, when selection will be changed or not needed anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the easiest way to do selection in the Visual Mode is to wrap a string into span and select this span using editor.dom.select.

```
    // We get editor's content, where 'editor' is a tinymce editor instance
    var content = editor.getContent();

    function selectText(start, end) {
    // We have start and end position of the text which we want to select
    // Then we wrap our word or frase between positions into span with unique id
    let content_with_span = content.substring(0, start) + '<span id="'+start+'_'+end+'">' + content.substring(start,end) + '</span>' + content.substring(end, content.length);
    // I keep the original 'content' variable outside, because in my case user can switch between various frases and when we switch to the next selection, we don't want to keep previos span in text

    // Return content with span into editor
    editor.setContent(content);

    // Create selection
    let selection = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('span[id="'+ start + '_' +  end + '"]')[0];

    // If selection exists, select node and move to it
       if (selection) {
          tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(selection);
          selection.scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "center", inline: "nearest"});
       }
    }
```

It works for me, and I hope it will help someone else.

Comment: the line  editor.setContent(content); should read editor.setContent(content_with_span);

Answer (score 0):

Here are a set of selection scripts that I'm using based on @tonyAndr solution above. I'm using this to build a bespoke spellchecker.

```
<script>

    var content = '';

    function selectionSet(start, end) {
    
        // span vars with unique id based on the section of text
        var spanId = 'id="' + start + '_' + end + '"'
        var spanClose = '</span>'
        
        // grab a copy of the current content 
        content = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();

        // wrap the section of text into the span 
        let content_with_span = content.substring(0, start) + '<span ' + spanId + '>' + content.substring(start,end) + spanClose + content.substring(end, content.length);

        // return the new content into editor
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content_with_span);

        // select the span
        let selection = tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom.select('span[' + spanId + ']')[0];

        // if selection exists, select node and move to it
           if (selection) {
              tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.select(selection);
              selection.scrollIntoView({behavior: "instant", block: "center", inline: "nearest"});
           };
    };
           
    function selectionClear() {
    
        // restore the previous selection (in my use case the user is not able to do other edits)
        //in the case of spellchecking - user has ignored the selected error
        if (content.length > 0) {
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
            content = '';
            };

    };
    
    function selectionReplace(start, end, replace_with) {
    
        //in the case of spellchecking - allow for the selection to be replaced with a new word
        if (content.length > 0) {
            let content_with_replace = content.substring(0, start) + replace_with + content.substring(end, content.length) ;
            tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content_with_replace);
            content = '';
            };

    };
</script>
```